# Elasticsearch high cpu usage and node queue high

Tags: elasticsearch, cpu-usage

My elastic cluster is getting high cpu usage some times.Performing some tests i found a node with a strange behavior in all cpu spike moments.

using **/_cat/thread_pool** i got this:

[image: search wave]

At this point , everything is ok in search.active in all nodes. But after some time ( 7 to 15 seconds) , all nodes show 0(zero) in search.active minus 6th node on list that continuos grow, and at this moment my cluster cpu get 100% of usage. This happen repeatedly with same node.

[image: node strange behavior]

Obs:

- This behavior is new in my cluster that goes running ok for 6 months more.
- Im using AWS Elasticsearch version 1.5

I believe that node is damaged. Have any way do confirm this?

Comment: do you have some control over your system? could  you move this index somewhere else to check that if its related to machine or to index?

Comment: @Mysterion The only thing I can do is change the number of nodes to force the instance of EC2 to be destroyed, but it is not a guarantee, and it is a production environment.

Comment: Did you find the issue? I've run into similar issues several times and so far no luck.

Comment: @mondkin yes. There is a broken node, I scale down and scale up to force node reconstruction.